# phpexcel switch to embedded cell image ？

Tags: java, python, php, c

I want to insert a picture into excel, but this picture is floating, I want it to be embedded in the cell instead of floating, and as the cell zooms in and out, how do I use PHPExcel?

```
        $objDrawing = new \PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
        $objDrawing->setPath(($pat));
        $objDrawing->setWidthAndHeight(80, 80); 
        $objDrawing->setOffsetX(7);
        $objDrawing->setOffsetY(7);
        $objDrawing->setRotation(0);
        $objDrawing->getShadow()->setVisible(true);
        $objDrawing->getShadow()->setDirection(50);
        $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A' . ($ki + 2));
        $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());
```

Using this method I can only get the floating picture, it is not embedded in the cell, if it is embedded, it will display this format: =DISPIMG("ID_1D2359FEC29049BAB368453095CDE910",1), is there any experienced master who can help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tas3l.png)